# Converting base64 image inside a cell in google sheet into an image in a cell

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, base64, google-sheets-api

Im having a problem with this since it actually worked before but the next day, it werent for some unknown reason. like it just stopped working in google sheet and throws error of "bad url" stuff even tho i used the same base64 that worked before and converted into an image

i tried other code, including a help from chatgpt but none worked so far,

so far this is what i have created that worked like yesterday

```
function insertImageFromBase64Src22() {
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
   var cell = sheet.getRange("M4");
   var data = cell.getValue(); // Your base64 data

   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
   var image = SpreadsheetApp.newCellImage().setSourceUrl(`data:image/png;base64,${data}`).build();
   sheet.getRange(4, 14).setValue(image);
 }
```

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253229/discussion-on-question-by-padua-edward-joseph-converting-base64-image-inside-a-c); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.